# How do i find if items in one array are present in the properties of different array filled with objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays. One containing different objects, the other just an array of numbers.

```js
let fofo = [
            {
                image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
                itemName: "Airmax",
                price: 105.99,
                gender: "Male",
                id: "20",
            },
            {
                image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
                itemName: "Airfly `99",
                price: 144.99,
                gender: "Male",
                id: "1",
            },
            {
                image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
                itemName: "Roshe 12",
                price: 99.95,
                gender: "Male",
                id: "2",
            },
      {
                image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
                itemName: "Roshe 12",
                price: 94.95,
                gender: "Male",
                id: "3",
            },
            {
                image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
                itemName: "Roshe 12",
                price: 111.95,
                gender: "Male",
                id: "4",
            },
            {
                image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
                itemName: "Roshe 12",
                price: 124.95,
                gender: "Male",
                id: "5",
            },
      ];
      
      
let mytester = [20,1,3]
```

I am trying to find objects in array "fofo" which match any item in the "mytester" array and return them into another array.

Comment: `mytester` array contains `id` only?

Comment: ```const output = fofo.filter(item => mytester.some(test => test == item.id));``` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achive this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let fofo = [{
    image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
    itemName: "Airmax",
    price: 105.99,
    gender: "Male",
    id: "20",
  },
  {
    image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
    itemName: "Airfly `99",
    price: 144.99,
    gender: "Male",
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
    itemName: "Roshe 12",
    price: 99.95,
    gender: "Male",
    id: "2",
  },
  {
    image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
    itemName: "Roshe 12",
    price: 94.95,
    gender: "Male",
    id: "3",
  },
  {
    image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
    itemName: "Roshe 12",
    price: 111.95,
    gender: "Male",
    id: "4",
  },
  {
    image: "../assets/Male/Male1.png",
    itemName: "Roshe 12",
    price: 124.95,
    gender: "Male",
    id: "5",
  },
];

let mytester = [20, 1, 3];

const result = mytester.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const isExist = fofo.find((o) => o.id === curr.toString());
  if (isExist) acc.push(isExist);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using `filter` and `includes`

```
var result = fofo.filter(f => mytester.includes(parseInt(f.id)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, You can use below code:

```
function getTheItem(){
 let arr = [];
 fofo.map((mainItem)=>{
    mytester.map((childItem)=>{
        var parsedId = parseInt(mainItem.id)
        if(parsedId === childItem){
          //here push it to a another array. 
          arr.push(mainItem);
        }
    }); 
 });
 retun arr;
}
```

**parseInt()** to parse the **mainItem.id** to int from string before the if block.